# mybatis EnumOrdinalTypeHandler use @Param return an error

Tags: mybatis

mybatis version 3.5.11

```
  @Insert({
        "insert into ENUMORDINALTEST (ID, NAME)",
        "values (#{row.id,jdbcType=INTEGER}, #{row.name,jdbcType=INTEGER,typeHandler=org.apache.ibatis.type.EnumOrdinalTypeHandler})"
    })
    int insert(@Param("row") Enumordinaltest row);



    @Insert({
            "insert into ENUMORDINALTEST (ID, NAME)",
            "values (#{id,jdbcType=INTEGER}, #{name,jdbcType=INTEGER,typeHandler=org.apache.ibatis.type.EnumOrdinalTypeHandler})"
    })
    int insert(Enumordinaltest row);
```

when i use  @Param("row") Enumordinaltest row
{row.name,jdbcType=INTEGER,typeHandler=org.apache.ibatis.type.EnumOrdinalTypeHandler}

mybatis send an error

```
Caused by: org.apache.ibatis.type.TypeException: Failed invoking constructor for handler class org.apache.ibatis.type.EnumOrdinalTypeHandler
```

if i do not use @Param it is ok
Enumordinaltest has an enum filed TestEnum

```
public enum TestEnum {
    FRED,
    WILMA,
    BARNEY,
    BETTY
}
```

i debug the soureCode and row.name can not find javaType

```
   private ParameterMapping buildParameterMapping(String content) {
        // row.name  
      Map<String, String> propertiesMap = parseParameterMapping(content);
      String property = propertiesMap.get("property");
      Class<?> propertyType;
      if (metaParameters.hasGetter(property)) { // issue #448 get type from additional params
        propertyType = metaParameters.getGetterType(property);
      } else if (typeHandlerRegistry.hasTypeHandler(parameterType)) {
        propertyType = parameterType;
      } else if (JdbcType.CURSOR.name().equals(propertiesMap.get("jdbcType"))) {
        propertyType = java.sql.ResultSet.class;
      } else if (property == null || Map.class.isAssignableFrom(parameterType)) {
        propertyType = Object.class;
      } else {
       // can not find the type
        MetaClass metaClass = MetaClass.forClass(parameterType, configuration.getReflectorFactory());
        if (metaClass.hasGetter(property)) {
          propertyType = metaClass.getGetterType(property);
        } else {
          propertyType = Object.class;
        }
      }
      ParameterMapping.Builder builder = new ParameterMapping.Builder(configuration, property, propertyType);
      Class<?> javaType = propertyType;
      String typeHandlerAlias = null;
      for (Map.Entry<String, String> entry : propertiesMap.entrySet()) {
        String name = entry.getKey();
        String value = entry.getValue();
        if ("javaType".equals(name)) {
          javaType = resolveClass(value);
          builder.javaType(javaType);
        } else if ("jdbcType".equals(name)) {
          builder.jdbcType(resolveJdbcType(value));
        } else if ("mode".equals(name)) {
          builder.mode(resolveParameterMode(value));
        } else if ("numericScale".equals(name)) {
          builder.numericScale(Integer.valueOf(value));
        } else if ("resultMap".equals(name)) {
          builder.resultMapId(value);
        } else if ("typeHandler".equals(name)) {
          typeHandlerAlias = value;
        } else if ("jdbcTypeName".equals(name)) {
          builder.jdbcTypeName(value);
        } else if ("property".equals(name)) {
          // Do Nothing
        } else if ("expression".equals(name)) {
          throw new BuilderException("Expression based parameters are not supported yet");
        } else {
          throw new BuilderException("An invalid property '" + name + "' was found in mapping #{" + content + "}.  Valid properties are " + PARAMETER_PROPERTIES);
        }
      }
      if (typeHandlerAlias != null) {
       // javaType is Object  than error
        builder.typeHandler(resolveTypeHandler(javaType, typeHandlerAlias));
      }
      return builder.build();
    }
```

i add a javaType  **javaType=com.xxx.wec.demo.dal.TestEnum** in the #{row.name} and is ok now.

```
@Insert({
            "insert into ENUMORDINALTEST (ID, NAME)",
            "values (#{row.id,jdbcType=INTEGER}, #{row.name,javaType=com.xxx.wec.demo.dal.TestEnum, jdbcType=INTEGER,typeHandler=org.apache.ibatis.type.EnumOrdinalTypeHandler})"
    })
    int insert(@Param("row") Enumordinaltest row);
```

Comment: It is a known limitation. If you use `EnumOrdinalTypeHandler` for all enums, you can set `defaultEnumTypeHandler` in the [config](https://mybatis.org/mybatis-3/configuration.html#settings) (in this case, you should not specify `typeHandler` in each parameter reference).

Comment: i do not think is what you said

Comment: i add the sourceCode debug

Comment: The limitation is that when you add `@Param`, MyBatis cannot resolve parameter type correctly in parsing phase because the parameter is passed as a `Map`.

Comment: so defaultEnumTypeHandler  can fix the limitation ?

Comment: Didn't it work? Be sure to remove the `typeHandler` from all parameter references `#{}`.

Comment: it work, if i do not  use EnumOrdinalTypeHandler for all enums, how can i do to fix

Comment: You already know how. Remove the `@Param` annotation.

Comment: I do a job  modify mybatis generator, add a param named schoolId after `Enumordinaltest row`. if I do not use @Param, It will cause an error

Comment: In that case, the easiest workaround may be to create a custom type handler for `TestEnum` instead of using the built-in `EnumOrdinalTypeHandler`. It is not ideal especially when there are many enums, but it is the easiest workaround at this moment, I think.

Comment: i find one solution and is it ok? i add  in the end

Comment: Yes, it's OK. Actually, just specifying `javaType` should work (i.e. you don't have to specify `typeHandler`). I was thinking about more complex scenario involving generics. I'm sorry about the confusion.

Comment: i remove the `typeHandler` and do not add `defaultEnumTypeHandler ` and it cause an error

Comment: I got confused with another similar question. You're right. As you are using non-default enum type handler, you need to specify `javaType` and `typeHandler`. You should add the solution you found as the answer and accept it yourself. These comments will be just confusing (my bad).